# C# DataGridview table с БД

Tags: c#

здравствуйте всем кто неравнодушен джунам), вообщем собираюсь написать мини программу на c# winforms, внутри база данных с Datagridview table, чтобы программа автономно, только для одного компьютера , чтоб в таблицу заносился данные и они внутри хранились , как лучше реализовать такую не новую идею ? через SQL server или же через Mysql server тогда надо будет сервер разворачивать...

Comment: Устанавливайте [MS SQL Local DB](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-RU/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb) *(имеется соответствующая опция в установщике Visual Studio)*, [SSMS](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-RU/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms), ORM *([EF](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-RU/ef/core/) или [NHibernate](https://nhibernate.info/))* и будет Вам счастье :)

Answer (score 1):

По моему, в Вашем случае лучшим решением будет [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html)

Его база данных хранится в одном файле. При этом Вы получаете все преимущества SQL - то есть, если Вам понадобится поиск, сортировка, отличная от дефолтной для DataGrid и т.п. - всё это можно будет реализовать, воспользовавшись проверенными решениями.

Можно, конечно, хранить набор записей просто в файле. Но Вам будет труднее адаптировать такое решение к Datagridview - он, всё таки, рассчитан  на то, чтобы работать с SQl _ подобными источниками данных.

Руководств по подключению SQLite к проекту на C# достатчоно моного, [вот](https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/21.1.php) [парочка](https://habr.com/ru/post/56694/)

Comment: metanit - отличный ресурс, и EFCore (ORM) - замечательный фреймворк.